# XAML - refine watermark code

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, binding

I am creating a log in page for my wpf application and want to add watermarks onto the username and password fields. I can achieve this by duplicating code but this is not a satisfactory solution for me. Is there a way I can pass string value through to the watermark binding seen in my Grid.resources section?

the goal is to refactor these two controls so they both can use the single resource login hint below, I have done research on this but came up short on information. Thanks

```
    <Grid.Resources>
        <VisualBrush x:Key="LoginHint" Stretch="Uniform"  AlignmentX="Left" AlignmentY="Center" >
            <VisualBrush.Visual>
                <Grid HorizontalAlignment="Left">
                    <TextBlock FontFamily="Corbel"
                       HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Center" Foreground="Gray"  FontStyle="Italic" Opacity="0.3"
                     Text="Enter Username"/>
                </Grid>
            </VisualBrush.Visual>
        </VisualBrush>
    </Grid.Resources>

 <TextBox FontSize="24" BorderBrush="#008AB8" BorderThickness="1" Grid.Row="1" x:Name="usernameTextBox" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" Margin="25">
    <TextBox.Style>
        <Style TargetType="{x:Type TextBox}">
             <Setter Property="Background" Value="Transparent"/>
                  <Style.Triggers>
                       <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding ElementName=usernameTextBox,Path=Text}" Value="" >
                                    <Setter Property="Background" Value="{StaticResource LoginHint}"/> 
                                </DataTrigger>
                            </Style.Triggers>
                        </Style>
                    </TextBox.Style>
                </TextBox>

                <PasswordBox FontSize="24" BorderBrush="#008AB8" BorderThickness="1" Grid.Row="2" x:Name="passwordMarkTextBox" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" Margin="25">
                    <PasswordBox.Style>
                        <Style TargetType="{x:Type PasswordBox}">
                            <Setter Property="Background" Value="Transparent"/>
                            <Style.Triggers>
                                <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding ElementName=passwordMarkTextBox,Path=Text}" Value="" >
                                    <Setter Property="Background" Value="{StaticResource LoginHint}"/>
                                </DataTrigger>
                            </Style.Triggers>
                        </Style>
                    </PasswordBox.Style>
                </PasswordBox>
```

Comment: I used this control, works nicely https://wpftoolkit.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=WatermarkTextBox

Comment: @user3904388 it won't work for `PasswordBox` because it does not have `Text` property but `Password` and anyway it's not `DependencyProperty` so you cannot bind to it

Comment: ah good point, I may need to reconsider my approach fundamentally.

Answer (score 0):

I would create a custom attached property (e.g., `WatermarkText`) and then create new control templates which bind to that value and superimpose the watermarks on top of the regular text area.  Use triggers to govern its visibility, showing it only when no text or password has been entered.  You may need a separate, readonly (computed) property to control its visibility in order to work with both `TextBox` and `PasswordBox`.